# Add a event handler to a control, Which way is more correct?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Add a event handler to the button control, Can be done in XAML

```xml
<Button x:Name="button" Click="Button_Click" />
```

Can also be done in C# code

```cs
button.Click += Button_Click;
```

Which way is more correct?

Comment: I would say it's just user preference.

Comment: `Which way is more correct?`, **none TBH**. Use bindings with commands...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are not ideal as you are supposed to use WPF with MVVM so you should dig into Databinding and Commands.
However, if you decide to ignore most features WPF gives you over WinForms and want to do it the old way it really comes down to personal preference on whether you like to do it in code or XAML.
Doing it in XAML however, has the advantage that you do not need to give a name to the control which will not make the button stay loaded in certain situations and save memory and improve program performance

if you want to use Events use them like this:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" />
```

And do not give names to controls.

Comment: `And do not give names to controls`, good luck with automated testing...

Comment: elaborate please @Çöđěxěŕ

Comment: If doing automated testing, having no names is a problem as some of the tests/scripts looks for UI elements by this name.

Comment: all tests I am running are testing the code and not the GUI but I guess nobody knows everything...from my current level of knowledge I still stick to my opinion as a control that has a name is always loaded while it could always be accessed via the name